# Post incrementation used with multiplication in while loop

Tags: c, syntax, post-increment

The odd numbers array is grouped in this way: `first` number is the first group, the next `2` numbers form the 2nd group, the next `3` numbers form the 3rd group and so on.

Groups:

1. 1
2. 3 5
3. 7 9 11
4. 13 15 17 19
5. 21 23 25 27 29

Now I want to find if a given number is the sum of the numbers in a group and find the order number of that group.

I wrote the next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);

    int x = 1;
    while( x * x * x < k )
        x++;

    if( x * x * x != k )
        x = 0;

    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I tried to change the `while` loop to the next one:

```
while( x * x * x++ < k )
    ;
```

The program is not working and I get the next warning in `codeblocks`:

`operation on 'x' may be undefined`

Why does it is not working?

Comment: Didn't saw that question. I wanted to detele this one because it's useless, but I can't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of `x * x++` is *undefined*. This is because you are essentially reading from and writing to `x` in an *unsequenced* step; multiplication is not a *sequence point* in C.

Don't do this in C. Your compiler is warning you of this out of common courtesy. Other compilers might eat your cat.

Comment: `Other compilers might eat your cat.` I wasn't ready for that. You made my day xD

Comment: This has been asked a million times before. Instead of answering the same old question over and over, please vote to close it as duplicate. A list of good duplicates can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info. In this case FAQ -> operators -> [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior).

Comment: @Lundin: The common duplicates on this are centred around the `=` operator, which is chiefly why I felt it appropriate to answer this one. `*` is more subtle, IMHO at least anyway. (And the reputation is immaterial: now I have the T shirt, the pen, and the mug ;-))

Comment: Could also use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: Alternatively you could just link to the C standard ;-). Personally I set the criteria for a duplicate as the *question* being an exact duplicate of another *question*. The fact that an answer to another question can serve to answer another question is not, to me at least, a test of "duplicateness".